# Deriving expression for probability of system failure.

Tags: probability

Output of a base station system consists of n parallel power amplifiers.
If we have k correctly working amps and we know that non-availability of each amplifier, at particular moment is given as $\frac{(1-A)}{k}$.

Assume that probability of amplifiers going down at the same moment is negligible and that they only can break one by one(also, assume that once broken, they cannot be fixed).

Base station works properly if if at least m out of n amplifiers work properly.

Derive the expression for probability of whole system going down.

I believe that it is safe to say that these events are mutually exclusive, but i am not sure which formula i am supposed to use here. I would have to determine expression for every single k and then sum it up to get the needed result, however, as i said, i can't tell what am i supposed to use in this case. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: After one amplifier goes down, it is removed and then system works just like that amplifier never been there (We could think of it as a new system with one amplifier less)

Comment: "at one particular moment"? If there is a non-zero chance that at any instant a given amplifier will fail and stay failed, then in any non-zero time interval (however short) ALL your amps will go down! Presumably you have a Poisson distribution, where the chance of a failure in a time interval $\delta t$ is $\lambda\ \delta t$ for some fixed constant $\lambda$, which might be $(1-A)/k$. Is that right?

Comment: @almagest well, eventually it will, but what i forgot to add is that broken amplifier gets removed from the system and then system works without it (it just has one less amplifier)

Comment: You are missing the point. You cannot have a non-zero chance of a failure at every instant. Suppose you had 1000 amps. Suppose there was a 1 in 100 chance of a failure in a picosecond. Then the chance of any given amp surviving for a microsecond would be about 1 in $10^{4360}$, in other words nil for all practical purposes. So all your amps would be dead before you had a chance to replace them. In fact they would all appear to fail instaneously. You have to think in terms of the chance of failure for a short time interval $\delta t$ being $\lambda\ \delta t$ for some constant $\lambda$,

Comment: @almagest By "one particular moment" i mean "every time i check it out, meaning, everytime i take a peek at what is going on in the system, for example, every week or so.

Comment: Fine. So you need to be precise about the "every week or so". Let's say an inspection every $w$ weeks. You find that on average $f$ amps have failed (I am not clear how this relates to your $k,A$). You replace the failed amps within $r$ weeks of the inspection. You want expected time to shutdown, which occurs if there are less than $m$ amps working. Presumably, you want the expected time to shutdown to be many years. The obvious model is a Poisson model and the calculation looks fairly straightforward. But have I given a correct description of the problem?

Comment: @almagest k is the number of correctly working amplifiers and there is no fixing them, we just remove them and then look at the base station as the whole new system, also, they can go down one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not really clear what the problem is. In any case, it is impossible to model any real situation exactly. I hope that this is close enough to give some insight. So I assume the following. A system has $n$ amplifiers. If less than $m$ are working, then the system fails. Every $w$ weeks the failed amplifiers are replaced. Accordingly, the system only fails if more than $n-m$ amplifiers fail between one replacement session and the next, ie within a period of $w$ weeks. What is the prob of a system failure over a period of $Nw$ weeks? In other words, what is the chance that over $N$ periods of $w$ weeks we never get enough individual amplifier failures to bring the whole system down.

We assume that the failure of any amplifier is independent of the others, and that this probability is independent of how long it has been in use. So the chance that it fails in a period of $w$ weeks is always the same, say $p$. Let $q=1-p$. Of course, the value of $p$ is not known a priori, but we can estimate it from the number of replacements needed. The expected number of replacements needed after $n$ weeks is $np$. So if $R$ is the average number replaced every $w$ weeks, then we estimate $p=R/n$

So the prob of $r$ failing in this period is ${n\choose r}p^rq^{n-r}$ and the prob of more than $n-m$ failing is $$f=\sum_{r=n-m+1}^n{n\choose r}p^rq^{n-r}$$

Unfortunately, there is no convenient closed form for this sum, so we have to switch to numerical work. Suppose we take $n=100,m=70$. The plot of $f$ against $p$ looks like this:

[image]

The shape is typical: there is a steep rise from nearly 0 to nearly 1 over a fairly small increase in $p$. If we keep the fraction $m/n$ constant at 70% then the rise happens at a larger value of $p$ as $n$ increases (and at a smaller value as $n$ decreases).

I assume that we want $f$ sufficiently small that the chance of no failure over $N$ periods of $w$ weeks is at least $0.99$, ie we want the chance of a system failure over a period of $Nw$ weeks to be less than 1%. So we need $(1-f)^N>0.99$ That requires roughly $f<0.01/N$. For example, to achieve a prob of no failure over $20w$ weeks we need $f<0.0005$

We get the following results:

$$\begin{array}{rrrr} & 60\% & \\ n & m & p & R\\ 50 & 30 & 0.21 & 10\\ 100 & 60 & 0.25 & 25\\ 200 & 120 & 0.29 & 58\\ 300 & 180 & 0.31 & 93\end{array}\hspace{1.5cm}\begin{array}{rrrr} & 70\% & \\ n & m & p & R\\ 50 & 35 & 0.13 & 6\\ 100 & 70 & 0.17 & 17\\ 200 & 140 & 0.20 & 40\\ 300 & 210 & 0.22 & 66\end{array}\hspace{1.5cm}\begin{array}{rrrr} & 80\% & \\ n & m & p & R\\ 50 & 40 & 0.06 & 3\\ 100 & 80 & 0.10 & 10\\ 200 & 160 & 0.12 & 24\\ 300 & 240 & 0.13 & 39\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think i understand it a bit better now, however, again, amplifiers are not replaced, they are removed completely and then we look at it as the whole new system with just one amplifier less(it would have one less amplifier but it still would be working) and analyze it under the same conditions.

Comment: Hold on. Initially you just remove them. Sure, and the system carries on with less amps. But at intervals (I assume a fixed interval of $w$ weeks) you replace them to bring the number back to $n$. Otherwise you would inevitably go below the minimum of $m$ after a while. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Well, i suppose that in that case, system would not be working at all (when n goes below the minimum)